# How do I store a status in MySQL easily?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, if-statement

I don't know PHP or SQL at all, only client-side scripting (HTML/JS). Basically, I would like to create a list with a few items which each can be added or removed by me. The functionality is so that if any of the items (`.item`) is clicked (well, if `.item.mark` gets clicked) a prompt shows "Would you like to mark this?" and if clicked yes, it gets stored in the SQL as 'marked', which results in a change of appearance. However if `item.remove` gets clicked, the mark gets removed.

**"Bonus points":** I want a prompt when the site is opened asking your name. The ID (#) gets hidden that equals the entered name

---

<sup>The thing that I would lik to create is an overview of each of my family members wishlist for Christmas. By marking each item it's shown that someone is buying that present.</sup>

---

*Apologies for asking almost a complete tutorial to create this, as it is actually not intended to do so.*

Comment: What is the `id` purpose ? Where do you want to store the person's name

Comment: Apologies for not seeing your comment. There will be multiple lists. Let' say `<ul id="Sander"><li>item</li></ul>` and `<ul id="Raja"><li>item</li></ul>`. With a prompt on load and JS `if <prompt.input = Sander { '#Sander.hide();`. Or something like that :)

Comment: Names don't have to be stored anywhere. If there is a match by comparing the name of input and the ID's (names of lists) than that ID should be hidden. After all, it wouldn't be fun to see what you are getting and what not. :) It would be better if this could be done with a Facebook log-in, but this would be much more complex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you indicated that you do not know PHP or MySQL at all, then I will address your question by providing you with a general answer as to how this can be achieved.  After that, I will provide you with my opinion why this is generally a bad idea.

> 1: Register event handlers in JavaScript/jQuery for the classes you
>   want to bind with, i.e. .item, .item.mark
>
> 2: Handle the 'click' by prompting the user to choose (yes/no) for the
>   target to be marked.  Target here means the item being clicked.
>
> 3: Get the user response (yes/no), and preferably format it as JSON
>   format (JavaScript Object Notation).
>
> 4: Send the JSON data to the server (this assumes that you have your
>   server configured, and that you have CGI enabled or have PHP or
>   any other server side scripting language setup to handle the request).
>
> 5: In the server, once the JSON data is received, the scripting
>   language, i.e. PHP, etc.,let us say it's PHP for now, it will open and
>   establish a database connection (this assumes that you have MySQL
>   configured and setup correctly), at which point, PHP will parse the
>   JSON data and input the data into the database.

So, this is generally how it is done, although there are variety of ways to implement it, for example, using AJAX and such, but it follows this general pattern.  Since you indicated that you do not know PHP and MySQL, and assuming that you do not know any other scripting language, it would be practical if you were to hire a web-developer to assist you with this, as this is a rather specific set of requirements that involve many other components that each require a level of expertise in.

Now, this solution does not take into consideration the detrimental security implications, that is an entirely different discussion that goes beyond the scope of this thread.

Would I implement it this way? Absolutely not. It would be helpful had you provided some technical background as to the nature of your application, i.e. server environment, do you know JavaScript/jQuery? Do you know any other scripting language? etc.

Hope this provided you with an insight that although conceptually simple, it does involve many components and consideration, including security implications and such.

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding "If you provided some more background info of this application". I wrote the functionality above and the description of the actual to be achieved application below in small characters. Basically a list of marked and not marked items, stored in a database, so the state of each item is saved. I do not know if this is the best way to do so, but I assumed this way. Besides the existing applications, as I would like to learn by doing.

Comment: For example, setting up MySQL alone correctly is a process, setting up your server is a process, setting your environment in the server to access requests from the front-end is a process, as I initially indicated in my response, there are allot of components all working together, if all you know is HTML/JS, then you should be able to easily implement section 1 through 3 and part of 4.  If you do not know MySQL and PHP like you said, then, it's worth reading about how to set them up in your environment, there are tons of online resources to get started by doing a general search.

Comment: I did clarify "providing background info" with "i.e. server environment, Do you know any other scripting language? etc." Generally, items 1 through 5 in my response show you the pattern that needs to be followed to achieve what you want. But it'll be helpful if you share whether you know any other scripting language, so that I can use that language to provide you with more detailed examples if that's what you want. I'm here to always help :)  However, this is an entire project really, touches on several components, and is rather specific. The type that I would hire or find someone to complete.

Comment: Oh, my apologies! I really looked over that. I've got an Apache server with Ubuntu 14.04 and MySQL and an available database running. I know more than enough of HTML and JS, so don't worry about that :) JSON on the other hand.. I do now know very much of that. As you wrote: 1-3 is a breeze and 4 gets a bit difficult. 5 I don't know at all :)

Comment: If on the other hand you want to do this by yourself, then, you would need to familiarize yourself with the following at the very least: 1:MySQL, 2: PHP, 3: JSON  Since you know HTML and JS, then you're solid, assuming you know JS fairly well.

Comment: This is getting a long comment range.. :) Anyhow, isn't it just "List, if clicked, send request to SQL "Change item X with value '0' to '1'.". If site is loaded, every item with value '0' is green and every item with value '1' will be marked red. Done. It seems so simple.; )

Comment: @SanderSchaeffer I'm giving it a try . Almost there

Comment: JS cannot send request directly to SQL, unless you're using Node JS etc. it needs to be processed by server, therefore, you need a scripting environment in your server, i.e. PHP; yes, every project  starts off as conceptually simple, like a no-brainer, until it boils down to actually implementing it.  I can provide you with a mini-tutorial that covers section 5 above, I would have to update my response later today though :)

Comment: No problem, take your time! I really appreciate this. If you can help me out, both of you, I'll buy you a beer as a token of my appreciation :)

Comment: @SanderSchaeffer Oupss Question Closed :(

Comment: I don't think I can change this question to make it not that broad and therefor a question that will not be closed. Perhaps message me on Facebook (/sanderschaeffer). The beer stays on :)